# Angular async pipe to Input property in child component not being set

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx

It seems like the child component only gets set the first time the Observable emits.

Container component (map operator added for debugging):

```
this.form$ = this.createOrderStore.pipe(select(getFormGroup)).pipe(
  tap((val) => {
    console.log('observable emitted');
    console.log(val);
    return val;
  })
);
```

Child component:

```
private _form: FormGroup;
@Input()
set form(val) {
  console.log('set form');
  if (val) {
    this._form = val;
  }
}
get form() {
  return this._form;
}
```

Container template:

```
<app-order-form [form]="form$ | async"></app-order-form>
```

The first time the observable emits, console shows 'observable emitted', val is undefined, then 'set form'.  However, since this first value is undefined, we don't set it in the template yet.

The second time the observable emits, console logs 'observable emitted', val is a complete form group (so it should trigger change detection), but 'set form' is not logged.  This second value is the one I actually need to set in the template.

Is there a reason why the child component property is only set the first time the observable emits?

Comment: You don't actually set the form more than once; when the Observable emits, it doesn't set the form. You should use the async pipe in the child template

Comment: it should fire. Are you sure the second one contains something, because angular checks by reference if it should update and `undefined === undefined`, so it won't enter the set function? try logging it in the observable (btw, for logging you can use `tap`, no need to return anything from that)

Comment: @PierreDuc I did what you suggested and edited the question.  For sure the second  time is the real value

Comment: Don't know why it doesn't work. But if you just need the second one, you can add a `filter` to the `form$` obs: `.pipe(filter((form) => !!form))`. Still doesn't explain it though

Comment: @PierreDuc So interestingly enough, I added the filter operator like you suggested, and 'set form' is still logged the first time like the filter didn't prevent the value from being emitted even though form is definitely undefined.  I'm really blown away here...

Comment: Ahh, now I know what's wrong :). I'll write an answer

Answer (score 2):

I believe your issue only happens when you have the `ChangeDetectionStrategy` to `OnPush`. You are setting the `this.form$` probably in the `ngAfterViewInit` hook, because of the `getFormGroup` method, am I right? There are two ways around this.

Easy way, using the `ChangeDetectorRef`

Container component:

```
constructor(readonly cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
   // ...

   this.form$ = this.createOrderStore.pipe(select(getFormGroup));
   this.cd.markForCheck();
}
```

Another way is to use a `Subject`, to update the formGroup, and have the `forms$` already be defined at class construction using

```
formGroup$ = new ReplaySubject<FormGroup>(1);

readonly form$ = this.formGroup$.pipe(
  mergeMap((formGroup) => this.createOrderStore.pipe(
    select(formGroup)
  ))
);

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
   // ...
   this.formGroup$.next(getFormGroup);
}
```

Just to clear up what happens in your code at the moment is that the `form$` property on the container component is undefined. That's the undefined you are logging in your child component, and because you are setting the `form$` inside the `ngAfterViewInit` hook, it does not get picked up by the change detector, unless you specifically tell it to go check

Comment: Change detection strategy is default.  I really don't want to have to do all this for something that's supposed to work the way I have it... I'm working on a stackblitz right now and hopefully I can reproduce it because I'm starting to feel like this may be a bug

Comment: @SeanIvins I haven't used angular without OnPush for a while anymore, so it could be that the same issue persist, just because you are setting it inside the life cycle hook. But if you do not use OnPush, I can only imagine that wrapping it inside a `setTimeout(() => this.form$ = this.createOrderStore.pipe(select(getFormGroup)))` will also work

Comment: @SeanIvins I've checked the docs, and yes, setting a property inside the `ngAfterViewInit` will require a second change detection cycle to be picked up

Comment: I am setting the property in constructor.  I have created a stackblitz that is basically exactly how I'm doing it, and it works... https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ccli97 I wish I could see what I'm doing wrong in my app

Comment: are you sure you have no typo `forms$ | async` vs `form$ | async`?

Comment: I've narrowed it down to some sort of race condition.  There's an ngrx update-reducers action that fires at some point.  If it happens before a certain action, it's broken.  If one of my actions fires first, then it works.  I'm going crazy over here

Comment: Mm, what does your createOrderStore looks like? Is this a hot or cold observable it returns?